# Too many arguments used by python scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm attempting to do some curve fitting within a class instance method, and the curve_fit function is giving my class instance method too many arguments.

The code is

```
class HeatData(hx.HX):
    """Class for handling data from heat exchanger experiments."""
```

then several lines of methods that work fine, then my function is:

```
    def get_flow(pressure_drop, coeff):
        """Sets flow based on coefficient and pressure drop.""" 
        flow = coeff * pressure_drop**0.5
        return flow
```

and the curve_fit function call

```
    def set_flow_array(self):
        """Sets experimental flow rate through heat exchanger"""
        flow = self.flow_data.flow
        pressure_drop = self.flow_data.pressure_drop
        popt, pcov = spopt.curve_fit(self.get_flow, pressure_drop, flow)
        self.exh.flow_coeff = popt
        self.exh.flow_array = ( self.exh.flow_coeff * self.exh.pressure_drop**0.5 )
```

gives the error

```
get_flow() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I can make it work by defining get_flow outside of the class and calling it like this:

```
spopt.curve_fit(get_flow, pressure_drop, flow)
```

but that's no good because it really needs to be a method within the class to be as versatile as I want.  How can I get this work as a class instance method?

I'd also like to be able to pass self to get_flow to give it more parameters that are not fit parameters used by curve_fit.  Is this possible?

Comment: I think I just need a way to call get_flow without invoking the self reference, which is apparently done automatically for bound methods whether "self" is passed as an argument or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlucky case, and maybe a bug in curve_fit. curve_fit uses inspect to determine the number of starting values, which gets confused or misled if there is an extra `self`.

So giving a starting value should avoid the problem, I thought. However, there is also an isscalar(p0) in the condition, I have no idea why, and I think it would be good to report it as a problem or bug:

```
if p0 is None or isscalar(p0):
        # determine number of parameters by inspecting the function
        import inspect
        args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(f)
```

edit: avoiding the scalar as starting value

```
>>> np.isscalar([2])
False
```

means that the example with only 1 parameter works if the starting value is defined as [...], e.g.similar to example below:

```
mc.optimize([2])
```

An example with two arguments and a given starting value avoids the inspect call, and everything is fine:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

class MyClass(object):
    def get_flow(self, pressure_drop, coeff, coeff2):
        """Sets flow based on coefficient and pressure drop.""" 
        flow = coeff * pressure_drop**0.5 + coeff2
        return flow

    def optimize(self, start_value=None):
        coeff = 1
        pressure_drop = np.arange(20.)
        flow = coeff * pressure_drop**0.5 + np.random.randn(20)
        return curve_fit(self.get_flow, pressure_drop, flow, p0=start_value)

mc = MyClass()
print mc.optimize([2,1])

import inspect
args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(mc.get_flow)
print args, len(args)
```

EDIT: This bug has been fixed so bound methods can now be passed as the first argument for curve_fit, if you have a sufficiently new version of scipy.
[Commit of bug fix submission on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/2fdf5ce)

Comment: Excellent!  I'm now running it like this: `popt, pcov = spopt.curve_fit(self.get_flow, pressure_drop,flow, p0=np.array([self.exh.flow_coeff]))` and it works beautifully.  I agree that this is a bug because if I'm giving a value for p0, it should use that to determine the number of arguments, even if p0 is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `get_flow` inside your `HeatData` class you'll have to have `self` as first parameter : `def get_flow(self, pressure_drop, coeff):`

EDIT: after seeking for the definition of curve_fit, i [found that the prototype is](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) `curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kw)` so the first arg must be a callable that will be called with first argument as the independent variable : 
Try with a closure :

```
def set_flow_array(self):
        """Sets experimental flow rate through heat exchanger"""
        flow = self.flow_data.flow
        pressure_drop = self.flow_data.pressure_drop
        def get_flow((pressure_drop, coeff):
           """Sets flow based on coefficient and pressure drop.""" 
           #here you can use self.what_you_need
           # you can even call a self.get_flow(pressure_drop, coeff) method :)
           flow = coeff * pressure_drop**0.5
           return flow
        popt, pcov = spopt.curve_fit(get_flow, pressure_drop, flow)
        self.exh.flow_coeff = popt
        self.exh.flow_array = ( self.exh.flow_coeff * self.exh.pressure_drop**0.5 )
```

Comment: I tried that, and then the error is

`get_flow() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)`

Comment: Try to add self as parameter when calling curve_fit(self.get_flow, self, ...)

Comment: Currently, I've got `def get_flow(self, pressure_drop, coeff):` and `spopt.curve_fit(self.get_flow, pressure_drop, flow)` and that's still giving the error `get_flow() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)`

Comment: What happen if you call `spopt.curve_fit(self.get_flow, self, pressure_drop, flow)` ?

Comment: Cool idea, but this is what it does: `get_flow() takes exactly 2 arguments (16 given)`

Comment: @Chad : I found th definition of curve_fit, I understand better the problem, see my edit.

Comment: defining get_flow within set_flow_array works.  However, I would ideally like to have get_flow available as a method in HeatData.

Comment: @Chad : you can, you can define get_flow as a standard instance method, but you'll still need a closure to encapsulate the call to `self.get_flow`

Answer (score 0):

Trying dropping the "self" and making the call: `spopt.curve_fit(get_flow, pressure_drop, flow)`

Comment: If get_flow is defined as a method of HeatData, then I get the following error by dropping the self: `global name 'get_flow' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of a class method definition should always be self. That gets passed automatically and refers to the calling class, so the method always receives one more argument than you pass when calling it.

Comment: What's kind of odd/cool, is that the word 'self' is merely a convention, and I could use the word 'hornswaggle' instead of self.  I guess this wouldn't be very descriptive coding practice though.

Answer (score 0):

The only pythonic way to deal with this is to let Python know `get_flow` is a `staticmethod`: a function that you put in the class because conceptually it belongs there but it doesn't need to be, and therefore doesn't need `self`.

```
@staticmethod   
def get_flow(pressure_drop, coeff):
    """Sets flow based on coefficient and pressure drop.""" 
    flow = coeff * pressure_drop**0.5
    return flow
```

`staticmethod`'s can be recognized by the fact that `self` is not used in the function.